# How to list Compiz keybindings in use?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

Other than looking though each active plugin and  manually searching for keybindings / keyboard-shortcuts  in use by compiz, is there a 'simple' way to gather this information?

i.e. Some panel that displays all currently active keybindings in use (by compiz), or some terminal command to do same.

Keyboard-shortcuts does not appear to list certain specific compiz shortcuts.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a (very long) one-liner that returns all shortcuts from all active plugins:

```
for i in $(gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins|sed "s/\[\|\]//g"|sed "s/,/ /g"); do echo "# $i:"; gconftool-2 -a /apps/compiz-1/plugins/"$i"/screen0/options | grep "_key\|_button\|trigger_\|initiate\ \|panel_first_menu\|keyboard_focus\|execute_command\|show_launcher" | grep -v "Disabled\|=[[:space:]]*$" | sort; done; echo -e "\n# metacity overrides:"; gconftool-2 -a /apps/metacity/global_keybindings | grep -v "disabled\|cycle\|switch_panels" | sort; gconftool-2 -a /apps/metacity/window_keybindings | grep -v "disabled" | sort
```

**Update**: 
Above version now gets *all* non-empty/disabled keybindings (key, mouse, key+mouse) from all active plugins.

However, the value of the key *X-GNOME-WMSettingsModule* in */usr/share/applications/compiz.desktop* makes Metacity override several Compiz keys. You will notice the italic labels in `ccsm` - that's when the value comes from Metacity and not Compiz.

As I found no easy way to fix this, I simply added all Metacity shortcuts to the end of the output.

Comment: That seems to do the job very nicely, thanks. Although it does return show_desktop_key = <Control><Alt>d, rather than <super>d as I have redefined it.

Comment: Now that's weird... changing the wall "left_key" changes "/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_left" instead. Seems **some** keybindings you change in Compiz are set for metacity? That would make the task a bit harder. :-/

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now shows the modified value for reveal desktop under # metacity overrides: -- Very nice job, Thanks again.

Comment: Note that since there are multiple commands there, if you want to save the output in a file, you should wrap that whole thing in parens and redirect the output after the trailing paren.

Comment: Thanks!  I note that in Precise 12.04, metacity doesn't seem to be running, so I guess folks would want to leave those last two parts out?  It might be easier to see and understand it all if you used multiple lines.

Comment: This no longer works as of 14.04: `No value set for /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to chain 2 sed scripts, they could be one, separated by ';'.  But even simpler would be piping to tr.  For 12.04 without metacity this should be:

```
for i in $(gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins|tr '[],' ' '); do echo "# $i:"; gconftool-2 -a /apps/compiz-1/plugins/"$i"/screen0/options | grep "_key\|_button\|trigger_\|initiate\ \|panel_first_menu\|keyboard_focus\|execute_command\|show_launcher" | grep -v "Disabled\|=[[:space:]]*$" | sort; done
```

However, as Jay_11 already noted, the whole construct seems to show part of what goes into compiz, not the result.  E.g. I get `close_window_key = <Alt>F4`, but I turned that off.  As an avid Emacs user I don't let a window manager get near anything except `<Super>`, but this doesn't show!

So the question remains: What is compiz really doing?

Answer (score -2):

i got a nice webpage for this ;)

https://web.archive.org/web/20110430205154/http://ranjith.zfs.in/ubuntu-10-04-compiz-fusion-keyboard-shortcuts/