# Unable to set a shortcut to grab screenshot area

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I currently have Ubuntu 13.10. At some point the default shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prn</kbd> stopped working.

Simply pressing <kbd>Prn</kbd> (captures the entire screen) works, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prn</kbd> to capture only active window works as well, only the shortcut for area clipping doesn't work for some reason.

Some more facts:

- Manually running `gnome-screenshot -a` works as expected!
- Changing the action to another key combo doesn't help
- Disabling the action and instead adding a custom shortcut with the command `gnome-screenshot -a` as answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170163/how-do-i-set-a-shortcut-to-screenshot-a-selected-area) doesn't help either

Here's a screenshot of my keyboard settings:

[image: Keyboard settings]

Any ideas?

P.S. In CompizConfig Settings Manager, the `Commands` plugin is turned **off**

---

**UPDATE** @falconer's answer has helped locate the problem, here's the output of a script that simulates key presses and dumps programs that intercept them:

```
$ xdotool keydown "shift+Print"; xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"; xdotool keyup "Print"; sleep 1; xdotool keyup "shift"; tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[ 25474.641] (II) Printing all currently active device grabs:
[ 25474.641] Active grab 0x4220d336 (core) on device 'Virtual core keyboard' (3):
[ 25474.641]       client pid 2196 xneur 
[ 25474.641]       at 25474411 (from passive grab) (device thawed, state 1)
[ 25474.641]         core event mask 0x3
[ 25474.641]       passive grab type 2, detail 0x0, activating key 50
[ 25474.641]       owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 1, confine 0, cursor 0x0
[ 25474.641] (II) End list of active device grabs
```

It's obvious from this log that in my case it was **xneur** (keyboard layout switcher program).

Comment: Just a very rare possibility: When you tried changing the 3 button combo, did you try to change it to a simpler 2 button combo or another 3 button one? Maybe your keyboard is started to die and now can't produce 3 button combos properly.

Comment: Hm, I changed it to `Ctrl`+`M` and it worked! But it's not the keyboard (my laptop if fairly new), I can assign it back to Ctrl+Shift+Prn or another 3 button combo so the keyboard AND the OS do register it. Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Btw the old screenshot had `Disabled` for `Take a screenshot of an area`, it was originally `Shift+Print`, I was just experimenting. Updated the screenshot now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made up a series of commands to show us the passive grabs on a keystroke. While the *Take a screenshot of the area* setting is set to Shift+Print please run this command and post its output.

```
xdotool keydown "shift+Print"; xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"; xdotool keyup "Print"; sleep 1; xdotool keyup "shift"; tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

This will trigger <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> keyevent and should show `gnome-settings-daemon` grabbing the keyboard.

Please also check if maybe some modifier key is activated on your keyboard and maybe somehow it is interfering with this keycombo. (e.g NumLock, ScrollLock, or some similar keyboard specific thing) Try out the combo with turning those modifiers on/off.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!!! That script was something I was looking for, I didn't know it's possible. Problem solved, **xneur** program is guilty!