# How to get a complete list of grabbed keys on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys

## Context

Modern desktop environment include features to adjust sound volume, interact with media players, and so on.

Here is an incomplete list:

- XF86AudioLowerVolume
- XF86AudioRaiseVolume
- XF86Battery
- XF86Calculator
- XF86Display
- XF86Explorer
- XF86HomePage
- XF86KbdBrightnessDown
- XF86KbdBrightnessUp
- XF86Mail
- XF86Messenger
- XF86MonBrightnessDown
- XF86MonBrightnessUp
- XF86PowerOff
- XF86Sleep
- XF86Suspend
- XF86TouchpadToggle

### Need

Sometimes a program already grabs some keys, which prevents proper operation of another. To fix this situation, one has to know which program already grabs the key, and adjust or disable them.

Each desktop environment provides a way to handle key shortcuts, but only theirs, not *all* keys that are grabbed by any random program connected to the X session.

How can I get a complete list of those grabbed keys on Ubuntu 18.04?

### Search before ask

These pages provide hints:

- [x11 - Find X.org pointer grab owner - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59141/find-x-org-pointer-grab-owner/62252#62252)
- [keyboard - Manipulating X key and pointer grabs on the command line - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line/273198)

The problem is: `xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo` does not list all keys.

For example, I was in an instance where [xfce pulseaudio-plugin](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/pulseaudio-plugin/start) grabbed at least 4 media keys, but on `XF86LogGrabInfo`, Xorg log would only list 3 ([example log, does not show XF86AudioPlay, XF86AudioRaiseVolume, XF86AudioLowerVolume,](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z8WGQpZ9qy/)).

Comment: Also, the links date back to 2013, and Xorg log is different from described: not "Printing all currently **active device** grabs:" but "Printing all **registered** grabs". Also, the trick in the other link with `sleep 1` does not change output at all. So, information on these links seems outdated, confirming need for some fresher information.

Comment: Other people having similar problems: [gnome - Unable to set a shortcut to grab screenshot area - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406543/unable-to-set-a-shortcut-to-grab-screenshot-area "gnome - Unable to set a shortcut to grab screenshot area - Ask Ubuntu"), [xorg - Keyboard shortcuts stop working intermittently - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925732/keyboard-shortcuts-stop-working-intermittently "xorg - Keyboard shortcuts stop working intermittently - Ask Ubuntu")

Comment: Active grabs are logged in `journalctl -f` (at least on my Ubuntu 18.04).