# media keys no longer work in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, media-buttons

Installed a bunch of updates to my Ubuntu 17.10 desktop tonight, and rebooted.  Now the media keys at the top of my DELL USB keyboard no longer work.

When I run `sudo showkey` it looks like the volume knob, play, stop, calculator, etc..., are still sending key down and key up events.  But those don't seem to do anything anymore, as if Ubuntu is ignoring all the extra keys.  Anyone have ideas?

```
sudo showkey
...
keycode 140 press # calculator
keycode 140 release
keycode 113 press # mute
keycode 113 release
keycode 166 press # stop
keycode 166 release
keycode 114 press # volume down
keycode 114 release
keycode 115 press # volume up
keycode 115 release

sudo lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2010 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:1003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the media keys (mute, play, pause) after installing the Unity interface on a clean 17.10 installation. The media keys worked fine in the login screen and on the Gnome interface desktop.

The post [How to find *why* I can't bind some keyboard shortcut (or which app took it)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265159/how-to-find-why-i-cant-bind-some-keyboard-shortcut-or-which-app-took-it) gave me an insight for a workaround. It seems to be some issue with compiz.

I installed Compiz Config Settings Manager

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

and disabled the plugin *Commands*. After that the media keys seem to be working fine.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` followed by `ccsm`.  Disabled the `Commands` plugin just like you wrote, and now my media keys work again.  Thanks!

Comment: OMG thank you! It broke for me at a non-descript moment a week ago, and I've been mad without my keyboard layout switching. This totally fixes the issue.

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: Didn't help me too.

Comment: works on 18.04 too

Comment: Same issue on 18.04. Media keys wont work, even after disabling commands. Can someone help

Comment: 18.04, Unity, you are my saviour, how could I survive without being able to open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl-alt-T</kbd>

Comment: If "Commands" is not selected, then select and deselect it. This worked for me in 18.04 with Unity installed and gnome-shell removed

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity installed, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/620427/173693) worked for me:

```
cd && mv .gconf .gconf.old
```

EDIT:

Subsequent Fix 1: Strangely, a couple weeks later, the problem came back, and while the accepted answer (disabling the "Commands" plugin) hadn't worked the first time, this time it did.  Not sure that plugin got re-enabled.

Subsequent Fix 2: 19 days after the above fix, the problem returned.  Toggling "Commands" plugin off and on fixed it.