# After latest kernel, keyboard shortcuts stop working

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcuts

After the most recent kernel update (4.13.0-26) my keyboard shortcuts usually stop working after returning from standby. Occasionally they will work for a time, but they almost always eventually stop.

Is there anyway to get them working again without rebooting? I've tried invoking unity in a command line, but this does a messy job of logging me out.

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Comment: If the last comment didn't help does this help?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983676/media-keys-no-longer-work-in-ubuntu-17-10