# Ctrl + Alt + T, volume keys, calculator key stop functioning

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME 3.26.2.
One of the last updates seem to have broken something.

Can't Volume up, Down, Mute, Calculator anynmore.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ( Open terminal ) not working either.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [media keys no longer work in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983676/media-keys-no-longer-work-in-ubuntu-17-10)