# Usual keyboard shortcuts changed after installing Unity in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, 18.04

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME normally, then I decided to install the Unity.

After that, the keyboard shortcuts have changed or even some of them do nothing.

For example:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a terminal, but it is not working anymore
Inside Terminator terminal I used to use this default shortcut:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> but now it opens `Emoji Choice` menu.

How can I fix it and turn back the default keyboard shortcuts?

P.S.: I did nothing more than just install Unity.

## UPDATE 1:

I installed the `compiz` as shown [on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983676/media-keys-no-longer-work-in-ubuntu-17-10).

This fixed the media keys that were not working in my keyboard, and I also could fix the keyboard shortcut for opening the terminal.

However, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>is still opening this `Emoji Choice` menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: @DavidFoerster actually it is different, although I have checked the solution you mentioned, the problem behavior is different. Even though the shortcuts are properly configured as the link you provided, there are conflicting ones as I mentioned above.

Comment: This is because of a [recent change to ibus](https://desktopi18n.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/ibus-1-5-18-is-released/). The answer is to [change the ibus setting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051387/167115).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the shortcuts is impossible to change with built-in system settings GUI. Most other system-wide shortcuts could be changed through `dconf` as [described here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings).

- Open Terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by default)
- `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
- `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to `desktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey`
- Further toggle `Use default value` and change the shortcut to `[]` as in the image below:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Open **Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts**. Once you're there, you can customize the shortcuts the way you want.

Comment: Yes, but still the Emoji Choice is the one that I most dislike when I push CTRL+SHIFT+E.

Comment: @phyloflash: Then change it as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut is introduced by [ibus release 1.5.18](https://desktopi18n.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/ibus-1-5-18-is-released/).

Disable the shortcut key by altering the hotkey item:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey '[]'
```

Revert/Reset to factory defaults using:

```
gsettings reset org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey
```