# How do I disable emoji input in Ubuntu Mate 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, emoji

Just noticed this annoying emoji input ("Emoji Choice") popping up every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in 18.04. I really need this shortcut to switch to the file explorer in Visual Studio Code but instead I only get the emoji input. Is there a way to disable this or at least change the shortcut? Don't want to change the VCS's shortcut because of this, I'm really used to it

Comment: The shortcut also conflicts with 'emphasis' in TeXmaker.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have exactly the same issue (although I'm on Mint MATE), and I can't trace which part of the system is responsible for this.

Comment: @Marcus yes, please read the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the keyboard shortcut for Emoji picker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039008/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-emoji-picker)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125726/how-to-disable-ctrl-shift-e-keybinding-from-showing-eeeee-and-loading-emoji-opti/1269239#1269239

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out it was the new ibus version that included the emoji package, I was able to change the shortcut in the ibus settings.

Comment: I got a fresh `Ubuntu 18.04.3` and there is no such thing as `ibus-setup` (unless you install ibus... even then, the suggestion does not help), no keyboard shortcut in the shortcuts, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> indeed triggers emoji mode... so they use another tool?

Comment: It's very odd. I've tested a live 18.04.3 Ubuntu Mate; there's no ibus package installed, and Ctrl+Shift+E does not enable the emoji input, but it still consumes one extra keypress. I've then tested 19.10 beta, and there's no ibus package installed, and Ctrl+Shift+E doesn't not enable the emoji input nor it consumes an extra keypress. I would therefore seem it's a bug in the input system.

Comment: For mysterious reasons, today an icon popped up, and it was ibus, which I don't remember installing (I'm not sure it's installed automatically). Note that since the last time I've posted the comment, I moved to Ubuntu MATE 18.04(.4). Anyway, since the icon popped up, removing the ibus hotkey(s) works. Not sure on your setup, but from mine is: `dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/hotkey/triggers "@as []"`. But I think this didn't work on Mint.

Answer (score 39):

Just a small hint: In case you don't find the IBus Preferences dialog, open a Terminal shell and type

```
ibus-setup
```

A dialog like this will appear on your screen:

[image: IBus Preferences dialog]

Comment: I had to run `sudo ibus-setup` due to https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2098

Comment: I was annoyed. Now I am excited! Now I use <Super>e as shortcut for emoji. But I recommend using `containing match`.  Happy typing <(^.^ )>

Answer (score 5):

**For VS Code if installed via Ubuntu Snap** you need an [input method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods/262220#262220) other than `ibus`.

If you run VS Code from command line do:

```
$ GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code
```

You can also add an alias for that in .bashrc: `alias code='GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code'`

To configure the Dash launcher (assuming VS Code is installed using Snap):

- The launcher file is located at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop` or `~/.local/share/applications/code_code.desktop`, or both
- Edit it and add `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` to `Exec` commands:

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
...

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
...
Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --new-window %F
Icon=/snap/code/41/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
```

Comment: If you download the official `.deb` version of VS Code, it works without changing the input method.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make any fix related to `ibus` work, but adding

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

to my `~/.profile` and restarting seems to have done the trick.