# Where can I find the configuration file for keyboard shortcuts in 12.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, configuration

Where can I find configuration file for keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You're talking about the file where system settings stores keyboard shortcuts correct?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/101248/15811 ?