# How do I set and store the custom Keyboard Shortcuts? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I would like to set and retrieve the *custom keyboard shortcuts* via commandline. I've found out how to set and restore the normal standard shortcuts using [gconftool-2](https://askubuntu.com/a/217310/17065) (and navigatable via gconf-editor).
I've also seen that apparently custom keyboard shortcuts are [stored in dconf](https://askubuntu.com/a/101248/17065), though I'm skeptical.

In attempting to use dconf to write and read the settings, it doesn't seem like the tool is updating the same setting. Can anyone help me find and update these custom keyboard shortcuts?

What I tried in dconf:

1. I set the shortcut:

   `dconf write '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0' "'<Primary><Alt>p'"`
2. I checked by opening up the unity dash, and going to 'keyboard' and 'keyboard shortcuts'. It didn't seem to be set.
3. Then I set my own shutcut on "custom0" to see if I used the wrong syntax. I set and cleared several times and called:

   `dconf read '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0'`
4. Even though other keyboard shortcuts are set, custom0 was the only one that returned values.

---

**Context:**
I'm trying to swap between pianobar and banshee multi-media keys. I found out about [pianobar ctl's socket](http://thisoldgeek.blogspot.com/2012/12/controlling-pianobar-pandora-client.html) used for sending keyboard shortcuts. I switch between sometimes and it's tedious to open up the keyboard shortcuts each time to update them. I've already figured out how to set the multimedia keys via:

```
gconftool-2 --set '/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/play' --type 'string' '<Primary><Alt>p'
gconftool-2 --set '/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/play' --type 'string' ''
```

---

Edit (2014-12-18):

I wonder if I'm going about this wrong. It doesn't seem like keyboard -> shortcuts has many commandline options.

CCSM also handles capturing keyboard shortcuts, is that at all configurable via commandline?

---

Note related, but not duplicate questions:

- [Where are GNOME keyboard shortcuts stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26056/where-are-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-stored)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've started doing something else here to solve my problem: https://gist.github.com/isaaclw/cbd3bf7bb13f5aefe987#file-multimedia-sh
I check for the program that's running and then run a specific qdbus command to start/stop the program instead of worrying about swapping key-bindings.

Comment: I could post it as an answer, but it's not really an answer to my specific question. It's just a different approach that others might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

To show all:

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case "keys\|hotkey\|keybind"
```

To get:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys calculator
```

To set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys calculator 'Hiragana'
```

For more info:

```
man gsettings
```

To easily get the values for "special" keys (multimedia, non-standard function keys):

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

*All these are standard in any recent Ubuntu; no need to install any additional tools.*

Comment: No thank you's needed, just accept the answer and upvote it (as I finally get to answer a question from a non-rep-1 user)  >:)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems to be pointing a helpful direction, but I'm stumped again. I currently have a keybinding set: "<Ctrl><Alt>p" which is running `/usr/local/bin/pianobar-ctl p` I know it because it's happening. But I don't see any reference to it in `gsettings list-recursively` so I'll need some other tool I guess to toggle that setting.

Comment: Actually looks like gsettings just loops back to dconf (which doesn't seem to work. `gsettings list-recursively | grep custom0` sends me to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0` which is what I tried to set with dconf, and didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: dconf uses the underlying gsettings, not the other way around.  And gsettings will allow you to enter things you can not necessarily do in dconf.
So in your particular case, you need to `gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case "alt+p\|alt>p"` and then remove all the [Alt][P] stuff that you find and then assign it to your custom shortcut.  If you post the output of the above command, I'll help you a bit further.

Comment: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot '<Alt>Print'`
`org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot '<Alt>Print'`

Comment: so no [Alt][P] defined anywhere. Good!  so what shortcuts do you want to define? (I don't have pianobar nor banshee)

Comment: I'm thankful for your attempts, but I question whether you've read my initial post. I don't think that this back and forth in the comments is helpful. If you don't understand my initial post, let's work on clarifying my question. It shouldn't matter whether you have any of my programs installed. If you disagree, then I need to work on my initial question.
I think I've shown so far that your attempts don't seem to helping me access the `gnome-settings-daemon` keyboard settings.

Comment: My apologies.  As lots of people have problems with keyboard short-cuts and propose solutions beforehand not knowing what they want, I always take a bottom-up approach (going from kernel upwards to find where their problem is.)  Apparently you *do know* **exactly** what you want, so I'll delete the entire conversation after you've left me a note as this doesn't seem to help you. :-)