# Is Ctrl + Alt + V a restricted key combo in 18.04?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Is Ctrl + Alt + V a system-owned or somehow restricted key combination in 18.04?

Original symptom behavior is that paste-formatting combo not working in google sheets.

Then searched the keyboard shortcuts and couldn't find ctrl + alt + v reserved

Then attempted to set it as a combination to a dummy command (clear), and found the settings utility wouldn't allow that combination to be set.

i.e.
trying to set ctrl + alt + v there was no response.
ctrl + alt + b would set just fine

- [shortcuts - no ctrl+alt+v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0uqa.png)
- [test shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQjDv.png)
- [ctrl+alt+v will not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjxJ.png)
- [ctrl+alt+b will set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwE0Z.png)

System:

- HP 15t laptop
- Dual-boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, an answer on this page lets you see a list of already used shortcuts. But I don't know how to show all the Global/Window/App/Access hotkeys at the same time. https://askubuntu.com/questions/101226/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-keyboard-shortcut-configuration?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for this guidance. Am attempting to run xev as described in the other post, but am not getting keystroke events, so am troubleshooting that.

Comment: @gskerry Could it be an instance of key jamming ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(keyboard)