# Any way to find keybindings currently in use? (ubuntu, compiz or otherwise)

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

Is there a good way to list or find out the keybindings that are currently in use on your computer? I'm changing some keybindings in compiz (particularly because I don't have a keypad) and I didn't want to take away from other plugins that are already using a particular keybinding. I know it isn't particularly a big issue as I could always assign a new binding as I need a command, but it can be difficult to keep track of.

I found this question: [How to list Compiz keybindings in use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42488/how-to-list-compiz-keybindings-in-use)

which gives two different codes in two different answers to supposedly list the bindings just for compiz, but it's severely outdated and both return a:

```
No value set for `/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins'
```

Also I didn't want to mix compiz bindings with ubuntu bindings or other bindings, so I was wondering if there was a way to list all bindings together. I thought it might be more efficient if there was a way or piece of simple software that could be run in the terminal and then output the command of any bindings. That way you could enter a key combination and it would give you the command of whatever it is bound to, or output nothing if that key combination is free.

Does anyone know of anything?

On a slightly unrelated note (but surely not worth its own topic/question), does anyone know what the begin key is? I came across some bindings with KPBegin, KPEnd, etc. and I know that end is obviously the end key. But begin is not the home key, that gives its own name, and I tried to look online but couldn't really find anything except some things suggesting it was the enter key, but this is return.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;) This site is quite different from a normal forum, so please [edit] your question and ask one question per, well... question, so can answer one of your questions... ;)